# how to construct a hash with multiples nested in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to construct a hash, the problem is that I have some customers that are buyers and others that are sellers that can have the same name and I need to group them in a hash by name. Something like this:

```
customers = {"name1": {"buyers": [id11,..,id1n], "sellers": [ids1,..,ids1n]},
             "name2": {"buyers": [id2,..,id], "sellers": [id1,..,idn] }}
```

The name is the key and the value is the hash with buyers and sellers, but I don't know how to initialize the hash and how to add a new key, value. 
Suppose that I have the `Customer.all` and I can for example ask:

```
Customer.all do |customer|
  if customer.buyer?
    puts customer.name, customer.id
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to include an example of the input here please?

Comment: can you show an example of how you get the names from the db and also how you know who is a buyer and seller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the block form of [`Hash.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-new) to set up each hash key that does not have a corresponding entry, yet, to have a hash as its value with the 2 keys you need:

```
customers = Hash.new do |hash, key|
  hash[key] = { buyers: [], sellers: [] }
end
```

and then you can loop through and assign to either the `:buyers` or `:sellers` subarray as needed:

```
Customer.all do |customer|
  group = customers[customer.name] # this creates a sub hash if this is the first
                                   # time the name is seen
  group = customer.buyer? ? group[:buyers] : group[:sellers]

  group << customer.id
end

p customers
# Sample Output (with newlines added for readability):
# {"Customer Group 1"=>{:buyers=>[5, 9, 17], :sellers=>[1, 13]},
#  "Customer Group 2"=>{:buyers=>[6, 10], :sellers=>[2, 14, 18]},
#  "Customer Group 3"=>{:buyers=>[7, 11, 15], :sellers=>[3, 19]},
#  "Customer Group 0"=>{:buyers=>[20], :sellers=>[4, 8, 12, 16]}}
```

---

For those following along at home, this is the `Customer` class I used for testing:

```
class Customer
  def self.all(&block)
    1.upto(20).map do |id|
      Customer.new(id, "Customer Group #{id % 4}", rand < 0.5)
    end.each(&block)
  end

  attr_reader :id, :name
  def initialize(id, name, buyer)
    @id = id
    @name = name
    @buyer = buyer
  end

  def buyer?
    @buyer
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
hsh = {}
Customer.all do |customer|
 if customer.buyer?
    hsh[customer.id] = customer.name
end
puts hsh
```

Pls, refer the following link to know more about [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) and [nested Hash](http://www.korenlc.com/nested-arrays-hashes-loops-in-ruby/)